# AJAX works when extension is .json but not when it is .html

Tags: json, ajax, spring-mvc

So I have an ajax request. When I use `.html` as below. I receive:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)
```

When i use `.json` I receive the correct output. Why does it not work with `.html`

```
    $("input[value = 'Add Type Targets']")
                            .click(
                                    function() {
                                        var promise = $
                                                .ajax({
                                                    url : '/MyRoot/budget/myUrl.html',
                                                    type : 'GET',
                                                    beforeSend : function(
                                                            xhr) {
                                                        xhr
                                                                .setRequestHeader(
                                                                        "Accept",
                                                                        "application/json");
                                                        xhr
                                                                .setRequestHeader(
                                                                        "Content-Type",
                                                                        "application/json");
                                                    }

                                                });

                                        promise
                                                .done(function(data) {
                                                           someCode
                                                      }
                                                 });
                                  });
```

On the method I have

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myUrl", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<String> getData() {
     return staticDataService.getData();
}
```

I have the jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10.jar and jackson-core-asl-1.9.10.jar added.

Is it that because of the .html extension my response header is getting altered. Actually it is not even hitting my method when i use .html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP error code 406 (Not **Acceptable**) means your HTTP request specified that the result must be of a certain type.
In your code, you explicitly mention that you only accept JSON results.

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/MyRoot/budget/myUrl.html',
    type : 'GET',
    beforeSend : function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader( "Accept", "application/json");
...
```

When the server sees a file with a .json extension, it will automatically give it an application/json content-type, while a .html file, with be text/html content-type.
Since these are very different, you see the 406 error.

Since you are actually returning JSON, I would suggest you also use that for the extension. Not only will this help prevent confusion for other developers, it will also prevent you from having to 'fight the system'.

If you for some reason do want the HTML extension, you could try forcing the response content-type to be application/json. Since this extension based content-type is typically added by the server (IIS, Apache, etc.), it depends on your development stack if you can override this.
In ASP.NET you would use the following to explicitly set a header, but I can't say for sure if this will override the settings in IIS.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json"
```

Should this not work, you can also change your AJAX call to be more permissive with it's response accepting.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader( "Accept", "*/*");
```

Comment: have tried that, if i do that the server returns with "Unsupported media Type" lots of threads on SO for that which say that we must add accept header. And that makes sense since we are sending json to the page